# On parallelizability of products.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I'm trying to prove or disprove the following statement.

---

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds. $M$ and $N$ are parallelizable if and only if $M\times N$ is parallelizable.

---

To prove the  direct implication, I reason as it follows:

$M$ and $N$ parallelizables implies $TM \approx M \times \mathbb{R}^m$ and  $TN \approx N \times \mathbb{R}^n.$ Hence
$$T(M\times N) \approx TM \times TN \approx (M \times \mathbb{R}^m) \times (N \times \mathbb{R}^n) \approx (M \times N) \times  \mathbb{R}^{m+n}.$$

But I can't justify the first diffeomorphism and I have read it's canonical, how can I see that without going deep in Category Theory?

I think the converse is false. I'm trying to see that $S^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ is parallelizable, but I can't find the 3 independent vector fields.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\pi_1 : M\times N \to M$ and $\pi_2 : M\times N \to N$ be projections onto the first and second factors respectively. Then $T(M\times N) \cong \pi_1^*TM\oplus\pi_2^*TN$. If $TM$ and $TN$ are trivial, then so is $T(M\times N)$. That is, if $M$ and $N$ are parallelisable, so is $M\times N$.

As you suspect, the converse is not true. To see that $S^2\times\mathbb{R}$ is parallelisable, note that it is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{(0,0,0)\}$ via the map $((x, y, z), t) \mapsto (e^tx, e^t y, e^tz)$. As $\mathbb{R}^3$ is parallelisable, it follows that $S^2\times\mathbb{R}$ is also parallelisable.

Comment: I don't understand why $T(M\times N) \cong \pi_1^*TM\oplus\pi_2^*TN$.